# Cocoa Application without any GUI?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have created a JAVA application (JAR) for Windows & Mac.

This JAR has all the required UI.

I thus need to create a cocoa application without any UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in info.plist

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Now the application doesn't appear in the dock and the menu bar won't be displayed.

All menu bar applications (menulets) work without an UI

Comment: Worked like a charm! :) 

Also, i am a newbie at objective -c, doing this opened the default GUI screen. could you guide me as to how can i ensure that no ui appears.

Comment: Delete the window in Interface Builder. You can even delete the file MainMenu.xib and remove the `NSMainNibFile` key and value in info.plist.

Comment: Perfect! :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784182/window-less-cocoa-application

this might be of additoinal help to others who are seeking an answer